# Combine jquery/jqueryui/qtip/custom javascript into one minified file

Tags: javascript, licensing, mit-license

I'm using jQuery, jQueryUi and qTip in my web application alongside custom JavaScript I've written.  All three of the JavaScript libraries I mentioned above are licensed under the MIT license.  From what I've read, I just need to include a copy of the MIT license for each of those libraries in my web application.

Is it OK to put each license as a separate file underneath a "licenses" directory of my project?  So, I would have a licenses directory with "jQuery-MIT-LICENSE.txt", "jQueryUi-MIT-LICENSE.txt" and "qTip-MIT-LICENSE.txt" in it.  Or, do I need to put the licenses right at the top of the JavaScript files?  Confused about where exactly these licenses need to be put in my web application...

What I'm ultimately looking to do is combine all of the JavaScript files into one minified version for faster loading and I want to put the licenses in whatever is the proper place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery puts this in their minified version, so I would say you would need to include something similar for each library you are including into the file for each library.

> /*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */

Comment: OK - if that's all that's needed, then that's great.  jQueryUi and qTip also do the same thing.  Do you think it's ok to combine all three plus my custom JS into one file as long as those headers are present?

Comment: I don't see an issue with that.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but wanted to make sure I didn't violate licenses.  Thanks.